# Having an odd problem with mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

Why am I not able to get inside the `while` loop in the `getCustomers()` function?

```
$stores = $bl->getStoresForGuide($gID);  //Returns 6 stores
$storelist = getStoreList($stores);      //Generate the HTML for the store list
$brandlist = getCustomers($stores);      //Generate the HTML for brand list

function getStoreList($stores) 
{
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($stores)) {
    // Do stuff 
  }
 //return result
}


function getCustomers($stores)
{
  echo mysql_num_rows($stores);  //Outputs 6

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($stores)) {
    echo "test "; // Outputs nothing
  }
  // Return some result
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looping twice. The first time you loop, you get to the end, and the pointer isn't reset before you loop again.

If you're sure you want to do this, check out [mysql_data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), and seek to the beginning of the result. Otherwise, I'd recommend just storing the results and iterating over the array.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. I put the result in an array, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getStoreList` first, then by the time you call `getCustomers`, `$stores` has already had all its rows fetched.